# Split the first portion of the string

Tags: split, asp.net-4.0

I have a string which is like this

> 187878 - my text comment - this is user comment - last

I have to take the first value, which is my employeeid i.e. 187878 and I need rest of the comment.

I use this,

```
string[] myText = textbox1.text.split('-');
```

but this broke the string into 3 peices and I am not able to get the comment as a whole. How can I get first id in a different variable and rest comment in different variable.

Do I need to loop again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the overload of [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx) that takes a count:

```
string[] myText = input.Split(new char[] { '-' }, 2);
if (myText.Length != 2) { /* error */ }
int employeeId;
if (!int.TryParse(myText[0], out employeeId)) { /* error */ }
string comment = myText[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
using System.Linq;

var firstPart = textbox1.Text.Split('-')
                                .First()
                                .Trim();

var lastTwoParts = textbox1.Text.Split('-')
                           .Skip(1)
                           .Take(2);
```

Comment: I am not getting .First() after Split. Could you help me please

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite : have you added using System.Linq?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex.  I dont remember the exact .net syntax (which depends on which language you are using), but the regex itself should be:

```
/^(\d+) - (.*?) - (.*?) - (.*)$/
```

Then you can pull apart the values using the groups.